# How to distribute patients equally to the doctors present in their area using SQL

Tags: sql

Consider the following two tables :

**Table 1 -  members**

**ID :** Unique ID of the patients.
**PIN :** PIN code of the patient's location.

```
create  table members (id varchar(255), pin varchar (255));
insert into members (id,pin)
values ('A','11'),('B','11'),('C','11'),('D','11'),('E','11'),('F','11'),('G','11'),('H','11'),('I','11'),('J','11'),('K','11'),
('L','99'),('M','99'),('N','99');`
```

**Table 2 - doctors**

**PIN :** PIN code of the doctor's location.
**NPI :**  Unique ID of the doctors.

```
create table doctors (pin varchar(255), npi varchar (255));
insert into doctors(pin,npi)
values ('11','123'),('11','456'),('11','789'),('99','987'),('99','654');`
```

[image: Input_tables]

My goal is to distribute patients equally to the doctors present in their PIN code.
e.g. 11 patients & 3 doctors resides in the PIN '11' , so each doctor should get patients equally, in this case, 4,4,3.

**Expected Output :**

[image: Output Table should look like this]

Could anyone help me please with this ?

Comment: Are you looking for a single SQL statement that generates your [output table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZLYn.png)?

Comment: Yes that would be great. (You can use join, union all , CTE, etc whatever required)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would approach this is as follows:

```
WITH drcte as
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as drcnt, pin FROM doctors GROUP BY pin
), 
memcte as
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) as memcnt, pin FROM members GROUP BY pin
), 
drids AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.pin ORDER BY d.npi) as drno, d.npi, d.pin FROM doctors d
),
finalcte AS
(SELECT m.id, m.pin,
CEILING(CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.pin ORDER BY m.id) as float) / CEILING(CAST(mc.memcnt as float) / d.drcnt)) AS drno
FROM members m 
INNER JOIN drcte d ON m.pin = d.pin
INNER JOIN memcte mc ON mc.pin = d.pin)
SELECT f.id, f.pin, d.npi
FROM finalcte f INNER JOIN drids d ON d.pin = f.pin AND d.drno = f.drno;
```

By way of explanation.  First we need to determine per pin how many patients to apply to each doctor.  For this we take the number of patients in each area and divide it by the number of doctors, rounding up to the nearest whole number (which is what the `ceiling` function does).  Note also the need to cast the numerator to a decimal, so that the result of the division is also a decimal.

We can then use this number itself as the divisor to the row_number of the patients, again rounding up to the nearest whole number.  This effectively batches the patients together, with a common batch number.  Finally we use this batch number to assign patient to a doctor number which we again achieve using row_number.

A final point to note is that we must use `OVER (PARTITION BY)` with the `row_number` function to reset the numbering for a new pin.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing this solution, it's exactly what I've been looking for.